# In pytest how can I avoid passing fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis, pytest-fixtures

I have a `flask app` and I'm trying to improve my `pytest` tests by using random data with `hypothesis`.
I have a fixture in `conftest.py` that yields a flask test client:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", name="client", autouse=True)
def fixture_client() -> FlaskClient:
    """Yield a flask test client."""
    app.testing = True
    app.secret_key = 'some_secret_key'
    # do something else before yielding
    yield app.test_client()
    # do some teardown
```

Then in my `auth_test.py` I have a function that I use for multiple tests:

```py
def _test_failed_registration(
        client: FlaskClient,
        flash_message,
        name=ValidUser.name,
        password=ValidUser.password,
        confirm=ValidUser.password,
        email=ValidUser.email
    ):
    """Common logic for testing failed registration."""
    with client:
        client.get("/")
        client.get(url_for("auth.register"))
        data = {
            "csrf_token": g.csrf_token,
            "name": name,
            "password": password,
            "confirm": confirm,
            "email": email}
        response = client.post("/auth/register", data=data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert flash_message in unescape(response.text)
    assert "Registration request sent. Please contact an admin." \
            not in response.text
```

For example one of the tests checks for a short username:

```py
@settings(max_examples=20)
@given(name=st.text(min_size=1, max_size=USER_MIN_LENGTH - 1))
@example(name="")
def test_failed_registration_short_name(client: FlaskClient, name):
    """test_failed_registration_short_name"""
    if not name:
        flash_message = "Username is required!"
    else:
        flash_message = (f"Username must be between {USER_MIN_LENGTH} and " +
                         f"{USER_MAX_LENGTH} characters!")
    _test_failed_registration(client=client,
                              name=name,
                              flash_message=flash_message)
```

This is working but the my problem is that I always have to pass the `client` fixture when calling `_test_failed_registration`, although I don't need it.

Is there a way to avoid this?
Something like:

```py
def _test_failed_registration(
        flash_message,
        name=ValidUser.name,
        password=ValidUser.password,
        confirm=ValidUser.password,
        email=ValidUser.email
    ):
    """Common logic for testing failed registration."""
    client = ?????
    with client:
        # same logic as before
        ...

@settings(max_examples=20)
@given(name=st.text(min_size=1, max_size=USER_MIN_LENGTH - 1))
@example(name="")
def test_failed_registration_short_name(name):
    """test_failed_registration_short_name"""
    # same logic
    ...
    _test_failed_registration(name=name,
                              flash_message=flash_message)
```

I'm trying to simplify the code so using wrappers and closure seems like overcomplicating things.

I tried using `request` from pytest, which works, but now I have to pass along the request:

```py
_test_failed_registration(request=request,
                          name=name,
                          flash_message=flash_message)
```

I tried decorating with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("client")` but I don't know how to access the client now:

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("client")
def _test_failed_registration(
        flash_message,
        name=ValidUser.name,
        password=ValidUser.password,
        confirm=ValidUser.password,
        email=ValidUser.email
    ):
    """Common logic for testing failed registration."""
    client = ?????
    with client:
        # same logic as before
        ...
```

Comment: I think your two options are to pass `request` and then access needed fixture(s) with _getfixturevalue_ or just pass the the client object.  IMO, keeping it as an explicit fixture and passing the client object is already exactly the right way to do it.  Fixtures are the best part of pytest... Do you want to explain why you want to eliminate client from your test? You say you "don't need it" but your function does use it, for a `get()`...

Comment: I only need the client fixture in the `_test_failed_registration` common logic function, not in `test_failed_registration_short_name` or all other tests that make use of the `_test_failed_registration`.